# wireless dropping constantly

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager

After using Ubuntu 22 LTS for almost a year, last week I started to face some issues with wifi, it will show a popup at the top of my screen saying authentication required, so I click in there authenticate and it starts to work again.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7BGR.png

This is happening every ~5 minutes.
running dmesg

```
[29074.327424] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country element
[29074.414263] wlp59s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea
[29111.321663] wlp59s0: disconnect from AP f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea for new auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76
[29111.402093] wlp59s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76
[29111.438630] wlp59s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (try 1/3)
[29111.440036] wlp59s0: authenticated
[29111.440214] wlp59s0: associating to AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 with corrupt beacon
[29111.441261] wlp59s0: associate with f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (try 1/3)
[29111.453573] wlp59s0: RX ReassocResp from f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[29111.456697] wlp59s0: associated
[29111.456898] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[29111.456901] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[29111.456904] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[29111.456906] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[29111.456907] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[29111.456909] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[29111.456911] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country element
[29111.460702] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 changed bandwidth, new config is 5180.000 MHz, width 2 (5190.000/0 MHz)
[29111.460709] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 changed caps/bw in a way we can't support (0x64/0x8084) - disconnect
[29111.460712] wlp59s0: failed to follow AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 bandwidth change, disconnect
[29132.290894] audit: type=1326 audit(1688400611.846:98): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=1 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=4082 comm="pool-org.gnome." exe="/snap/snap-store/959/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=93 compat=0 ip=0x7f17a2bcac4b code=0x50000
[29188.755293] wlp59s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76
[29188.792586] wlp59s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (try 1/3)
[29188.794259] wlp59s0: authenticated
[29188.794634] wlp59s0: associating to AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 with corrupt beacon
[29188.797360] wlp59s0: associate with f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (try 1/3)
[29188.812428] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[29188.815806] wlp59s0: associated
[29188.816199] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[29188.816207] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[29188.816215] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[29188.816220] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[29188.816225] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[29188.816230] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[29188.816235] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country element
[29188.878796] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 changed bandwidth, new config is 5180.000 MHz, width 2 (5190.000/0 MHz)
[29188.878812] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 changed caps/bw in a way we can't support (0x64/0x8084) - disconnect
[29188.878819] wlp59s0: failed to follow AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 bandwidth change, disconnect
[29189.299234] wlp59s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86
[29189.302348] wlp59s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86 (try 1/3)
[29189.304219] wlp59s0: authenticated
[29189.304795] wlp59s0: associating to AP f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86 with corrupt beacon
[29189.307823] wlp59s0: associate with f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86 (try 1/3)
[29189.320996] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=4)
[29189.325015] wlp59s0: associated
[29189.325274] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[29189.325283] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[29189.325407] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[29189.325413] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[29189.325418] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[29189.325423] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[29189.325427] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country element
[29189.382802] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86 changed bandwidth, new config is 5180.000 MHz, width 2 (5190.000/0 MHz)
[29189.382818] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86 changed caps/bw in a way we can't support (0x64/0x8084) - disconnect
[29189.382824] wlp59s0: failed to follow AP f0:2f:74:ef:f1:86 bandwidth change, disconnect
[29189.755615] wlp59s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea
[29189.758620] wlp59s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea (try 1/3)
[29189.861412] wlp59s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea (try 2/3)
[29189.863002] wlp59s0: authenticated
[29189.865401] wlp59s0: associate with f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea (try 1/3)
[29189.878603] wlp59s0: RX AssocResp from f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[29189.882580] wlp59s0: associated
[29189.883115] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[29189.883123] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[29189.883131] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[29189.883137] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[29189.883141] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[29189.883146] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[29189.883150] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country element
[29189.953987] wlp59s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea
[29325.033981] wlp59s0: disconnect from AP f0:2f:74:ef:f2:ea for new auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76
[29325.099408] wlp59s0: authenticate with f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76
[29325.137051] wlp59s0: send auth to f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (try 1/3)
[29325.138668] wlp59s0: authenticated
[29325.138787] wlp59s0: associating to AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 with corrupt beacon
[29325.141684] wlp59s0: associate with f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (try 1/3)
[29325.155230] wlp59s0: RX ReassocResp from f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=1)
[29325.158147] wlp59s0: associated
[29325.158270] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x833a
[29325.158273] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[29325.158276] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[29325.158278] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[29325.158279] ath: Country alpha2 being used: GB
[29325.158281] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[29325.158282] ath: regdomain 0x833a dynamically updated by country element
[29325.170437] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 changed bandwidth, new config is 5180.000 MHz, width 2 (5190.000/0 MHz)
[29325.170445] wlp59s0: AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 changed caps/bw in a way we can't support (0x64/0x8084) - disconnect
[29325.170448] wlp59s0: failed to follow AP f0:2f:74:ef:f3:76 bandwidth change, disconnect
```

network manager logs: `journalctl -f -u NetworkManager`

```
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.6462] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.6463] device (wlp59s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.6468] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.6879] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.50.195
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.7312] device (wlp59s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.7438] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.7439] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.7976] device (wlp59s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.7980] device (wlp59s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.7984] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
NetworkManager[762]: (src/core/devices/wifi/nm-device-wifi.c:3341):activation_success_handler: runtime check failed: (priv->current_ap)
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.7994] device (wlp59s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.8369] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495062.8370] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.0709] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.0710] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.1785] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.1786] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2022] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2022] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2022] device (wlp59s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2482] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): canceled DHCP transaction
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2482] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2483] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): state changed no lease
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2483] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2487] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2487] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2488] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.2500] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495063.3110] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): state changed new lease, address=192.168.50.195
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495064.8553] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3117] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3118] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> authenticating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3121] device (wlp59s0): ip:dhcp4: restarting
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3123] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): canceled DHCP transaction
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3124] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3124] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): state changed no lease
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3126] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3251] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3251] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3389] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.3389] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4091] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4091] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4095] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4096] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) disconnected during association, asking for new key
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4097] device (wlp59s0): state change: activated -> need-auth (reason 'supplicant-disconnect', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4322] dhcp4 (wlp59s0): canceled DHCP transaction
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4329] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.4341] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> disconnected
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.5142] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495100.5143] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8283] device (wlp59s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8286] device (wlp59s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8289] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'MN1436224DPS' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8290] Config: added 'ssid' value 'MN1436224DPS'
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8290] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8290] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8290] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8291] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8291] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8798] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8798] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> authenticating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8813] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.8813] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.9064] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.9064] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.9130] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495104.9130] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.0704] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> group_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.0704] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: 4way_handshake -> group_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.0707] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: group_handshake -> disconnected
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.0708] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: group_handshake -> disconnected
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.1765] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.1766] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4016] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4017] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> associating
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4276] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4277] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> associated
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4346] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4346] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4way_handshake
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4476] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: 4way_handshake -> completed
NetworkManager[762]: <info>  [1688495105.4476] device (wlp59s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "MN1436224DPS"
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?